# If Application class variable points to an activity class variable then after activity gets destroyed will there be a memory leak or not

Tags: java, android, arraylist, memory-leaks

In my `Application` class there is an ArrayList and there is also an `Activity` where I have also created an ArrayList now after initialising this ArrayList, I am referencing the Application class ArrayList to this activity class ArrayList.

Now I was thinking about that when this activity will get `destroyed`(User presses back button), so I think the activity class ArrayList memory must get released, but because as same memory is also referenced by App class ArrayList so now will there be a `Memory Leak` or not ??

And if there will be no `Memory Leak` then please tell me when I store my activity/fragment context in a static variable then there happens `Memory Leak` but why not here.

**Application** Class code

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
     ArrayList<String> contacts;
}
```

**Activity** Class code

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("123");
((App) getApplication()).contacts = arr; // Here I am refrencing arr to contacts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when this activity will get destroyed(User presses back button), so I think the activity class ArrayList memory must get released

In Java — and other languages using garbage collection — the closest thing to "released" is "has no more references pointing to it".

In this case, the `ArrayList` still has a reference pointing to it: the `contacts` field in the `Application`. Hence, the `ArrayList` cannot be garbage collected.

> now will there be a Memory Leak or not ?

There is no way for that `ArrayList<String>` ever to be garbage-collected, since you will always have a reference to it.

However, we tend to reserve the word "leak" for cases where the memory usage is bad:

- You did not intend to hold onto a reference indefinitely
- You keep adding more objects to the list, and so your memory usage grows indefinitely
- Etc.

Whether this is "leak" or not depends entirely whether this is expected behavior (e.g., you are using this `ArrayList<String>` as a cache of data obtained from outside the app, such as from disk or the network) or not.

Comment: I am using this arraylist to store data which comes from backend but I still need to store it when activity is destroyed that's why storing it in my APp, now will there be memory leak or not ?? ALso please tell me why when I store my activity/fragment context in a static variable then there happens Memory Leak but why not here.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur: "now will there be memory leak or not ?" -- I cannot answer that. Whether this is "leak" or not depends entirely whether this is expected behavior. "when I store my activity/fragment context in a static variable then there happens Memory Leak" -- activities and fragments are destroyed by the framework, after which they are useless. Holding a reference to a useless object is a memory leak. I cannot say whether your `ArrayList<String>` is useless.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur Until you save the data, then it is not a leak, as you still need it. Once you save the data, you don't need it anymore, then if you don't release it will be a leak. At that point, you should call `contacts.clear()` or set `contacts` to null. Now keep in mind, a useless ArrayList of some Strings, is not a terrible leak, while holding on to a dead activity, is a much bigger waste.